# how to calculate sum(theta^n/( n(n + 1))) from 0 to inf

Tags: probability, summation

I am doing the following summation:
$$
\sum{\frac{\theta^{n}}{n(n+1)}}, n=1,2, \ldots, 0<\theta<1
$$

I tried to use the technique $\sum\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \sum(1/n)-(1/(n+1))$, but didn't know how to continue to deal with the $\theta^n$.

Any hint or help?

Comment: What happens if you integrate twice the sum $\sum\theta^{n}$ termwise?

Comment: See the Taylor series for the natural log function

Comment: Oh, dear! I forgot the Taylor series! Thank you!

Comment: Perform partial fraction decomposition on denominator (as you have already done). Then use series for natural logarithm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k(k+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2633937/evaluate-sum-k-1-infty-fracxkkk1) (also [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3210006), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1457451), ...)